# How to require "password" when booting into Android on Acer Aspire One AOD250?

Tags: android, acer-aspire, acer-aspire-one

I have an Acer Aspire One AOD250 which comes with a dual-booting system with Android and Windows XP.  When I boot into Android, it goes straight to the home screen without any verification of my identity, unlike Windows requiring a user password, or the funny grid that you get on some Android phones.

I want to ensure that if it gets stolen, that someone can't just turn it on and start reading my emails, etc.  How do I do this?

Comment: What happens if you turn on a lock pattern/PIN from Settings > Location and Security?

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting a password in the BIOS of the laptop.
That way nobody could do anything at all without a password.

Comment: I would also reccommend setting a BIOS password, they are extremely secure.